# DataGridTemplateColumn does not bind the object from ItemSource (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I create an object type `Message` than a list `TableDataGrid_ItemSource = new ObservableCollection<Message>()`. 
Before I had only `DataGridTextColumn` columns and they were all binding the correct types of object Message.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding MessageCategoryID.Type}" Width="*"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Full text" Binding="{Binding FullTextMessage}" Width="*"/>
```

Now I want to customize a column by adding a text and an image both types of `Message` object.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Message ID">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding MessageID, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="*" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When I run I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.

Comment: Wild guess `Source="{Binding Image}"` is the problem! What is the DataType of `Image`?

Comment: I actually checked with a random picture in my solution and it works just fine. I think the problem is the binding from the object to datagridtemplatecolumn.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Label  Width="*"
```

this is the source of your trouble.
`Width="*"` - it is only for Columns and Rows. Remove it.
  If you want to Stretch your `Label` and `Image`, replace your `StackPanel` by Grid.
`StackPanel` make its children size minimal.